# What aliased IP client is connecting to?

Tags: ip-aliasing

On my server (FreeBSD 9.2-RELEASE) I have several aliased IP addresses from one subnet:

```
192.168.0.1/24
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.3
```

And I am wondering how to correctly detect to wich particular IP a client is connecting to (the remote host IP - src-ip - is known)?

The main problem is that a client can already be connected to one IP and I want to know whether it is connecting to another IP-address.

The final goal is to accept or deny a connection based on the username (it is known) and dst-ip of client.

Comment: What application? What language?

Comment: For TCP use `getsockname`. For UDP don't bind to `::` but instead create multiple UDP sockets and bind one to each local IP address.

Comment: Application is Dante (proxy server). I am not really sure what you mean "what language"? I think it have to be _a shell command_ to find out known src-ip (client) is connecting to what dst-ip (server) right now.